# Sort Function Deleting portion of array, C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting

I have this very weird issue going on. The function you will see in a moment is supposed to ensure that all elements (chars) in a 2D array are at there utmost position, that is, there is no empty space above any of the characters. For instance a board could look like this:

```
1 X * * X ^
2   * X ^ *
3 o o * X ^
4 o ^ X X X
5 ^ * X * ^
  1 2 3 4 5
```

And there is an issue at (2,1) because there is an empty space above a non empty space.

My function does the sorting correctly but it deletes any character in the bottom row that has an empty space above it. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why. Here is my sort function.

```
int bb_float_one_step(BBoard board){
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < board->rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < board->cols; j++){
        if (board->boardDim[i][j] == None && (board->boardDim[i + 1][j] != None && i + 1 <= board->rows)){
            char tmp = board->boardDim[i + 1][j];
            board->boardDim[i + 1][j] = board->boardDim[i][j];
            board->boardDim[i][j] = tmp;
            }   
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < board->rows; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < board->cols; j++){
    printf("%c",board->boardDim[i][j]);}printf("\n");}
}
```

Below Is a picture of the full sequence, The Program prints a board. The user is asked to select a region to 'pop.' A function then replaces all the characters that are connected with a blank space. Then in the last portion of the picture you can see how the characters are deleted. The board that doesn't have a border is there because I was using it to check if the characters actually were deleted or not.
[image]
Thank you in advanced for 1, reading this whole post, and 2, any help you can give.

Comment: `i + 1 <= board->rows` doesn't seem promising.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is remove all the empty spaces and then move those empty spaces to the end of the array (the last row).  If that's the case, if you implemented your board as a 1-d array, it becomes a simple function call to move the spaces to the end and "squeeze together" the remaining characters.

Comment: Debuggers are your friends, try using one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are comparing current row with next row you should use `for(i = 0; i < board->rows-1; i++)`
Then in your complex if statement, get rid of `&& i <= board->rows`. That should have been a less-than anyway, not less-than-or-equals. You're going out of bounds and getting garbage in your array.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the row beyond the maximum number of rows.
(board->boardDim[i + 1][j] != None && i + 1 <= board->rows)
That memory is not guaranteed to be 0.  If it is not 0, your function will swap it in.  If it is not human readable, printf won't print anything for it thereby shifting the | to the left.